# How to find subdependency version?

Tags: python, dependencies

In the pydata-sphinx-theme, we realized that Sphinx version is pinned to 5.3.0 when the latest one is 7.0.2 (https://github.com/pydata/pydata-sphinx-theme/issues/1441).

We checked that we are not pinning it in our own dependency list:

```ini
[project.optional-dependencies]
doc = [
  "numpydoc",
  "myst-nb",
  "linkify-it-py", # for link shortening
  "rich",
  "sphinxext-rediraffe",
  "sphinx-sitemap",
  "sphinx-autoapi",
  # For examples section
  "ablog>=0.11.0rc2",
  "jupyter_sphinx",
  "pandas",
  "plotly",
  "matplotlib",
  "numpy",
  "xarray",
  "sphinx-copybutton",
  "sphinx-design",
  "sphinx-togglebutton",
  "jupyterlite-sphinx",
  "sphinxcontrib-youtube",
  "sphinx-favicon>=1.0.1",
  # Install nbsphinx in case we want to test it locally even though we can't load
  # it at the same time as MyST-NB.
  "nbsphinx",
  "ipyleaflet",
  "colorama",
]
```

How can I pin point which of our dependencies has a hard upper bounds ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly answering the question but here is a workaround to debug my personal issue.

### When do you need to do it ?

You have a dependency version that has an upper bounds but you are not the one setting it. It obviously come from one of your depedency but you cannot identify which one.

### How to debug ?

force the dependency you want to upgrade to latest version, it will trigger a dependency conflict upon install and point you to the lib including to an upper bounds.

### Example

In my case, I wanted to update Sphinx to 7 so I added:

```
Sphinx>=7
```

Which trigger a conflict with `myst-nb==0.17.2`.